# How do I get scss working with a react project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass

For days I've been trying to set up a react project wether with react-create-app or my own webpack configuration that integrates scss in some way. I always get some weird dependency issue with wepack (can't find right version whether it be 2.2.1 or 1.4.1). Does anyone have an idea about how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Id say a good place to checkout would be the create react app docs which have a whole section dedicated to this very question. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it

package.json dependencies :

```
"css-loader": "^0.26.1",
"node-sass": "^4.4.0",
"sass-loader": "^4.1.1"
```

(or whatever the latest version are)

webpack.config.js module loaders :

```
{ 
    test: /\.scss$/, 
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
}
```

inside your code (root file if possible)

```
import './<your style path>/<your style file>.scss'
```